# No. of even non-negative solutions of an equation involving $d$ variables

Tags: combinatorics

I want to know the number of non-negative solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_d = 2n$ where each of $x_i$ is even.

Comment: do you want the answer or hint?

Comment: answer. I need to use it to some other problem.

Comment: This is the same as the number of non-negative integer solutions of $y_1+\cdots +y_d=n$. Using Stars and Bars (see Wikipedia) the answer is $\binom{n+d-1}{d-1}$. Note that I really do mean $n$, not $2n$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Say you have $2d$ balls in a row, and $d - 1$ partitions. In how many ways can you place the partitions in the row of balls to split the into $d$ groups such that each compartment is even?

[image]

Apply this to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a case of  Counting the number of ways of placing $n$(in this case $2n$) indistinguishable objects into $k$(in this case $d$) distinguishable boxes.[which is the same as counting the number of $n$-combinations for a set with $k$ elements when repetitions are allowed.]

Therefore the answer is $^{d+2n-1}C_{2n}=\frac{(d+2n-1)!}{(2n)!(d-1)!}$